# Store JSON from Node.js to SQL server

Tags: json, sql-server, node.js, ssms

I am extremply new to this kind of development and I am trying to get through this at my best. 
I am fetching JSON data from my client side, and strying to send these into sql database. I am using SSMS 2012. 
I get an idea of inserting those values (in the code), but what should I do to store these JSON into SQL database? Is there any way better than I attempted to do? 
Below are detail information, please let me know if something is unclear.

**JSON**

> {"GradeA":25,"GradeB":36,"GradeC":32}

**sql_Table**

> GradeA | GradeB | GradeC

**backend**

```
    app.post('/ping', function (req, res) {
  res.send(res.body);
  var jsondata = JSON.stringify(req.body);
  var test = JSON.parse(jsondata);

  var values = []; 
  values.push(test.GradeA, test.GradeB, test.GradeC)
  console.log(values);

  var dbConn = new sql.Connection(config);

  dbConn.query("INSERT INTO RMS (GradeA, GradeB, GradeC) VALUES ?", [values], function(err, result, fields){
    if (err) throw err;
    //if no error, resulst return as follow
    console.log(result);
    console.log("Number of rows affected :" + result.affectedRows);
    console.log("Number of records affected with warning : " + result.warningCount);
    console.log("Message from MySQL Server : " + result.message);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

You are using `JSON.stringify` instead of `JSON.parse`:

```
let json = '{"GradeA":25,"GradeB":36,"GradeC":32}';
let jsondata = JSON.stringify(json);
console.log(typeof jsondata);  // string

let datajson = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(typeof datajson);  // object
console.log(datajson.GradeA);  // 25
```

Next, it's a really bad idea to make database query in a `for` loop.

Also note you can't send HTTP response more than once.

Comment: I get the json object part,, so what should I do to store properly ?

Comment: Loop on your object to prepare _values_ and make only one insert query. Then, in the callback, you can send the response.

Comment: I updated my bcknd code. And I get a ConnectionError.. would you please take a look?

Comment: Note that in your updated code, _config_ is not defined.

Comment: it was defined above the code, i just didn't have them included